# Build URL string

Tags: string, url, powershell

Trying to build a link with a variable and a string, but I always get a space in between them. How can I fix this?

The `$sub` is a `SPWeb` object from sharepoint.

```powershell
Write-Host $sub.Url "/default.aspx"
```

result:

`https://intra.mycompany/pages/sales /default.aspx`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `$sub` variable inside the string literal so that it is treated as one string:

```powershell
Write-Host "$($sub.Url)/default.aspx"
```

Note that you will need to use a [sub expression operator `$(...)`](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html) since you are accessing an attribute of `$sub`.

---

Another approach, depending on how complicated your string is, is to use the [`-f` format operator](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2013/03/11/understanding-powershell-and-basic-string-formatting.aspx):

```powershell
Write-Host ("{0}/default.aspx" -f $sub.Url)
```

If you have many variables that you need to insert, it can make for cleaner and easier to read code.

Comment: Apologize for my deplorable spelling and grammar.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `URL` class' constructor to do the join, rather than using string manipulation.  This will have the additional advantage of automatically take care of appending any slashes required.

```
function Join-Uri {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Alias('Path','BaseUri')] #aliases so naming is consistent with Join-Path and .Net's constructor
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [System.Uri]$Uri
        ,
        [Alias('ChildPath')] #alias so naming is consistent with Join-Path
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$RelativeUri
    )
    process {
        (New-Object -TypeName 'System.Uri' -ArgumentList $Uri,$RelativeUri)
        #the above returns a URI object; if we only want the string:
        #(New-Object -TypeName 'System.Uri' -ArgumentList $Uri,$RelativeUri).AbsoluteUri
    }
}

$sub = new-object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{Url='http://demo'}

write-host 'Basic Demo' -ForegroundColor 'cyan'
write-host (Join-Uri $sub.Url '/default.aspx')
write-host (Join-Uri $sub.Url 'default.aspx') #NB: above we included the leading slash; here we don't; yet the output's consistent

#you can also easily do this en-masse; e.g.
write-host 'Extended Demo' -ForegroundColor 'cyan'
@('default.aspx','index.htm','helloWorld.aspx') | Join-Uri $sub.Url | select-object -ExpandProperty AbsoluteUri
```

Above I created a function to wrap up this functionality; but you could just as easily do something such as below:

```
[string]$url = (new-object -TypeName 'System.Uri' -ArgumentList ([System.Uri]'http://test'),'me').AbsoluteUri
```

Link to related documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hst1w91(v=vs.110).aspx